# How to model an event based architecture?

Tags: android, events, architecture, uml, cloud

I have to build an aplication in android that is similar to Evernote, and i have to make a diagram model that shows the app's architecture. So, textualy my app works that way:
I have a MVC model that control the access to the database (in a cloud) and i have a based event model that verefy (when the user access the app in another smartphone) if the database have a modification, so then, the aplication will synchronize the SQLite with the Cloud.

So, the problem is that i have to model this, and i only know how to model the mvc.
Can someone help?

Comment: Your question is very vague and hard to answer. Could you add more information about the app and maybe even some initial drawings you have tried to do?

Comment: Ok,i will try to explain better. In my app the user can write notes and embed photos in a note, then the app save this in the SQLite, and if have internet, save in a cloud too. If the user log in the app in another smartphone, the app will synchronize whats have in the cloud with the Smartphones SQlite. For this, my doubt is: how to model an goodarchtecture for this. Because i was thinking in a MVC model for conection with cloud and an MVC model to conect with the SQLite and a Event Based Model to verify the sychronization.

Answer (score 0):

It always depends on the details of your implementation and exactly what you want to present with your model and to whom.

Now I assume that you have some classes for your events and some other classes with the event handlers. I would create class diagrams to show the associations between event classes and handler classes. Then maybe you want to model the event handler methods with activity diagrams or sequence diagrams.

In an event based architecture it is not unusual to draw some state diagrams in order to present state transitions of your objects. It depends again on the details of your design that you think are significant to present.

From your question I understand that you don't think that your design is something very complicated that requires a lot of modelling, so probably you don't need that much modelling.

Comment: In my case, i only need to show an architecture that the developer should follow. It should be in a high level, most basic than a class diagram, but i liked the idea of a state diagram. The big problem is that i have to draw the event based model unificated with the mvc model. Its basically this:
A MVC model that cotains a MVC in the Model, and have too a Event Based Model between.

Comment: I don't think that it's necessary to create only one class diagram. Your diagrams aim at helping people understand, will they miss any point if you create two class diagrams or more? And don't underestimate sequence or collaboration diagrams. Based on my experience, they help the developer understand better what they need to code.

Comment: May i have expressed bad what i want. I just need a architecture model, to analyse if in the end of the project, my project is too distant from the initial architecture. Because of this, it may be in a more high level.